# Upload laravel to sever in Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed my laravel project in to the Cpanel by following these steps

1. Copy all files and folders to mail folder (Public_html)
2. Move all files and folders to root folder.
3. Change the DB also in the .env file.
4. Change the bootstrap path in the index file.

Now I am getting 500 error. When I checked "autoload.php" file, I see that there is no "composer/autoload_real.php" folder and file in the path. Even no folder at all.

I am New to `laravel` and uploaded my first project to Cpanel. Please help on this.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: enable error reporting to see what is actual error.

Comment: check `.htaccess` file as well if you are using apache server. And I guess root folder means `public_html` here.

Comment: Yes, root folder is public_html

Comment: It is working now. It was a permission issue.